# Use grep to find the words that have two 's' separated by a space

Tags: linux, terminal, grep

I'm trying to use grep to find the words that have two 's' separated by a space, then two 's' or more in the words, and then the  words that contain exactly two 's'.

I already tried these commands

```
ls|grep -E 's+'

ls|grep -E 's+'|grep \s

ls|grep -E s{2,\}
```

The two first commands print all the words that contains 1 's' or more, that isn't what I'm looking for, and the last command prints all the words that contain two 's' side by side ...

Btw, I'm also having trouble to find the exact same output of "grep -c", without the "-c" argument ...

For example `ls -R| grep s` prints 14k approximately, and I want to find the same result, without -c

Thanks in advance

Comment: See: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/74329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep "s s"
grep "s.*s"
grep -E "^[^s]*s[^s]*s[^s]*$"
```

Comment: Work super fine, THANKS man. Do you have any clue concerning this part of the thread : Btw, I'm also having trouble to find the exact same output of "grep -c", without the "-c" argument ...

For example ls -R| grep s prints 14k approximately, and I want to find the same result, without -c ?