# Grep exclude mount point by name when executing df

Tags: linux, macos, grep

I have 2 mount points:

- /Volumes/Media
- /Volumes/Media Backup 1

When I execute `df | grep -e /Volumes/Media`, both mount points are returned. I would like to be able to exclude `/Volumes/Media Backup 1` from the results.

Comment: `df | grep -E '^/Volumes/Media$'` returns nothing.

Comment: Try `df | grep -E '[[:blank:]]/Volumes/Media$'`

Comment: It is really strange to see a question involving `grep/sed/awk` getting closed with the reason that is is not about software development :)

Comment: Not strange at all ... use of single commands is pretty much *never* to be considered programming, and much better off on [unix.se] or [su], where it would most likely be closed as a dupe. I understand that it's easy reputation gained, however ;)

Comment: How about closing it as dupe, then? :P https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660584/use-grep-to-find-the-words-that-have-two-s-separated-by-a-space

Comment: There are literally hundreds and thousands of single command answer on SO and those are all related to **software development** only. You are welcome to create a meta post if you want to raise objection to it so that SO can change policy. btw what is your take on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73187932/548225) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73697221/548225) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73588418/548225).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use any of these solutions:

```bash
# grep with end anchor and whitespace matching at start
df | grep -E '[[:blank:]]/Volumes/Media$'

# awk with non-regex approach that matches last field
df | awk '$NF == "/Volumes/Media"'

# sed that uses similar regex as grep
df | sed -n '\~[[:blank:]]/Volumes/Media$~p'
```